# access redux store for login data into different component

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have an application wherein I am trying to access the user data stored in the redux store.

To achieve that, I created a arrow function to the component wherein I am trying to access the same -

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.auth.user,
}); 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DashboardScreen);
```

I did the import for connect

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

Now when I try to access it in the function  -

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('The user is : ');
    console.log(this.props.user);
    this.setState({categories : cat})
}
```

But I am getting it as undefined.

Here is the Reducer file :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const initialAuthState = { isLoggedIn: false };
const Login = 'Login';
const Logout = 'Logout';
export const login = data => ({
  type: Login,
  data
});

export const logout = () => ({
  type: Logout,
});

function auth(state = initialAuthState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Login:
      console.log("reducer called for Login");
      console.log(action.data.username)
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: true, user: action.data.username };
    case Logout:
      console.log("reducer called for logout");
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: false, user: {} };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
});

export default AppReducer;
```

Can anyone suggest as to what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: put where you dispatch the login and how

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `user` from the state while you have placed `isLoggedIn` in  `initialAuthState`. You can do is to check `isLoggedIn` from the state like

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.auth.isLoggedIn, <— use `isLoggedIn` here —>
});
```